# return the value of the clicked li in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

So I am using jquery.autocomplete.js,
demo can be found here http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html
I want to be able to return a span value in an alert message.
this is the php file that echos results:

```
$email="span id='emaild'".$rs['email'].'/span'; $str.= $email." ".$rs['phone']." ".$rs['address1']." ".$rs['address2']." "."\n"; echo $str;
```

email is inside a span tag. when I click on that result I want to be able to see an alert of that value, that is the email.
This is what I have so far, it displays a 0 zero on the alert box as a result

```
 .click(function(event) {           
            var keyw = jQuery("li").val();
            alert(keyw);
            $(target(event)).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
            select();
            // TODO provide option to avoid setting focus again after selection? useful for cleanup-on-focus
            input.focus();
            return false;

        })
```

Comment: Please use the `code` button for code and not `blockquote`.

Comment: kk thanks Im new to this site sorry. I found the solution I used  var keyw = $(target(event)).text();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method instead of `val`:

```
var keyw = jQuery("li").text();
```

The `val` method is used to return the value of the `value` property, and the only elements that have `value` properties are those which are used in forms, such as `input` or `select`.

Comment: ah okay thanks for clearing that out. when I used span instead of li since the email is between span tags, it returned all the emails in the loop. any idea on how to return the one clicked?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) Inside the `click` event handler, `this` will refer to the clicked element. It will refer to the DOM element itself, so you need to pass it into jQuery: `$(this).text();`

Comment: var keyw = $(this).find("span").text(); that returned only the span text. but it still displays all elements in the loop. its not returning the value of that one li element I am clicking.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. What is the `click` event handler bound to?

Comment: this is the code: list = $("<ul/>").appendTo(element).mouseover( function(event) {
   if(target(event).nodeName && target(event).nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'LI') {
             active = $("li", list).removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE).index(target(event));
       $(target(event)).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);            
         }
  }).click(function(event) {
   //on click what happens
   
   var keyw = $(this).find("span").text();
   alert(keyw);

Comment: if you search for var keyw in http://abbotent.com/js/jquery.autocomplete.js thats the file

Answer (score 4):

`.val()` only applies to form elements. Use `.text()` or `.html()` to get the content's of elements.